# How to display a transparent opaque background when the search bar is active with hooks?

Tags: react-hooks, react-context

I am trying to change the background when the search bar is active and the card component containing all the images and description goes transparent using react-hooks and the context api.
There are no errors.

Hi, This is the sample project i want to create [similar  project](https://windbnb-by-sachin.netlify.app) when you click on the search bar the background gets faded.

[Link to the project](https://codesandbox.io/s/windbnb-hft2i?file=/src/components/Header/NavSearch/NavSearch.js)

Comment: Please create a "minimal reproducible example". If you just want to toggle class you can add onclick "onClick={(ev)=>{toggleClass(ev)}}" with a function. I am not sure from what you described what the problem is? or where you are stuck?

Comment: Hi, This is the sample project i want to create https://windbnb-by-sachin.netlify.app/ when you click on the search bar the background gets faded.